# Docker can't start on centos7: failed to start docker application container engine

Tags: docker, centos7

centos7 via vmware workstation player, and

```
[root@localhost Desktop]# uname -r
3.10.0-229.14.1.el7.x86_64
```

first, `yum install docker-engine` 
then, `other_args="--selinux-enabled" >> /etc/sysconfig/docker`
when `service docker start`,I got error:

```
[root@localhost Desktop]# systemctl status docker.service -l
docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled)
   Active: activating (start) since 日 2015-10-25 19:49:32 PDT; 46s ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
 Main PID: 14387 (docker)
       CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
           └─14387 /usr/bin/docker daemon -H fd://

10月 25 19:49:32 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker     Application Container Engine.
10月 25 19:49:32 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit docker.service entered failed state.
10月 25 19:49:32 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
10月 25 19:49:33 localhost.localdomain docker[14387]: time="2015-10-25T19:49:33.092885953-07:00" level=info msg="[graphdriver] using prior storage driver \"devicemapper\""
10月 25 19:49:33 localhost.localdomain docker[14387]: time="2015-10-25T19:49:33.093697949-07:00" level=info msg="Option DefaultDriver: bridge"
10月 25 19:49:33 localhost.localdomain docker[14387]: time="2015-10-25T19:49:33.093729432-07:00" level=info msg="Option DefaultNetwork: bridge"
10月 25 19:49:33 localhost.localdomain docker[14387]: time="2015-10-25T19:49:33.108983655-07:00" level=warning msg="Running modprobe bridge nf_nat br_netfilter failed with message: modprobe: WARNING: Module br_netfilter not found.\n, error: exit status 1"
```

who can help me ? thanks.

Comment: What do you get when your enter `netstat -r`?

Comment: Also, https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/15498

Comment: After I "yum install docker-selinux", I see docker route information while "netstat -r", and "service docker start" is now successful.thanks John Giotta!